# Ensure list of dicts has a dict with key for each key in list

Tags: python

Context:
I'm using an Ajax call to return some complex JSON from a python module. I have to use a list of keys and confirm that a list of single-item dicts contains a dict with each key.

Example:

```
mylist=['this', 'that', 'these', 'those']

mydictlist=[{'this':1},{'that':2},{'these':3}]
```

How do I know that mydictlist is missing the "those" key? Once I know that, I can append {'those':4} to mylist. Simply checking for "those" won't work since the list is dynamic. The data structure cannot change.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you saying that you cannot simply check that each list item is [```in```](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations) the dictionary?

Comment: Right, because the list changes in different cases

Comment: @wwii: More than one `dict`; the naive approach would require iterating `mydictlist` once for every value in `mylist`, which is `O(n*m)` (where `n` and `m` are the lengths of the two `list`s), both worst and expected case. Better solutions can reduce the work to `O(n + m)`, which could make a difference if the `list`s are large.

Comment: Is it possible for ```mylist``` to have duplicates?

Comment: @wwii no, it will always have unique items

Comment: Can you explain ```The data structure cannot change.```?

Comment: In an e-commerce context, mylist is a list of item attributes (price, size, etc), so the site where these items are sold will always have a list of attributes to return. The single-item dicts are also fixed and come from some python classes (for various item types) which define what attributes an item "should have". The list of single-item dicts gets pulled in by my ajax call on the site, and this returned JSON format must stay consistent in order to support my Angular app on the front end. My app fails if I get a list of single-item dicts, lacking one of the dicts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple code is to convert your search list to a set, then use differencing to determine what you're missing:

```
missing = set(mylist).difference(*mydictlist)
```

which gets you `missing` of `{'those'}`.

Since the named `set` methods can take multiple arguments (and they need not be `set`s themselves), you can just unpack all the `dict`s as arguments to `difference` to subtract all of them from your `set` of desired keys at once.

If you do need to handle duplicates (to make sure you see each of the `keys` in `mylist` at least that many time in `mydictlist`'s keys, so `mylist` might contain a value twice which must occur twice in the `dict`s), you can use `collections` and `itertools` to get remaining counts:

```
from collections import Counter
from itertools import chain

c = Counter(mylist)
c.subtract(chain.from_iterable(mydictlist))
# In 3.3+, easiest way to remove 0/negative counts
c = +c

# In pre-3.3 Python, change c = +c to get the same effect slightly less efficiently
c += Counter()
```

Comment: This is great so far. I get: set(['those']), which I can iterate over to populate a "missing keys" list.

Comment: @JacobIRR: Ah, I used the Py3 `repr` for `set` in my answer, but you'd see it as the equivalent non-literal syntax in Py2. You don't actually need to iterate the `missing` result explicitly; `missing = list(missing)` converts from `set` to `list`, or `missing = sorted(missing)` to get a sorted `list`.

Answer (score 0):

The most straightforward way is to iterate over both the containers and check:

```
for key in mylist:
    if not any(key in dic for dic in mydictlist):
        print key, "missing"
```

However, if you have a lot of keys and/or dictionaries, this is not going to be efficient: it iterates over `mydictlist` once for each element in `mylist`, which is O(n*m). Instead, consider a set operation:

```
print set(mylist).difference(*mydictlist)
```

Comment: Why limit it to a single key from each `dict`? I mean, sure, the example code has one key per `dict`, but it's actually easier to just slurp them all.

Comment: True dat, 'specially since I don't care in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

The pandas package is a great way to handle list of dicts problems. It takes all the keys and makes them column headers, values with similar keys populate the same column.

Check this out:

```
import pandas as pd

mydictlist=[{'this':1},{'that':2},{'these':3}]

# Convert data to a DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(mydictlist)

# List all the column header names and check if any of the key words are missing
df.columns
```